# redirect stdout of exec'd command without using shell metacharacters

Tags: perl

```
exec 'foo.sh > foo.out'
```

causes problems, due to the command being called through a shell rather than directly exec'd. How can I set up the redirection to `foo.out` first and then just `exec 'foo.sh'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open(STDOUT, '>', 'foo.out') or die $!;
exec 'foo.sh', @args;
```

And to guarantee "direct execution" in case `@args` is empty,

```
exec { 'foo.sh' } 'foo.sh', @args;
```